# How to Mock the Lambda expression using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, junit5

How to Mock the Lambda expression using Mockito

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("A");
items.add("B");
items.add("C");
items.add("D");
items.add("E");
```

lambda

```
items.forEach(item->System.out.println(item));

items.forEach(item->{if("C".equals(item)){System.out.println(item);}});
```

Comment: Please explain your question instead of only including a link; and please do not post a picture of code, but include the code as text in your question.

Comment: Add code snippet and statement which you are trying to mock

Comment: @Jesper  code added

Comment: @ygbgames code added

Answer (score 1):

Aside from discussing the purpose of doing this - practically you need to extract consumers from forEach() to separate methods (with the default modifier at least), and in your test class you should use Mockito.spy() functionality to mock them.

(If you haven't yet familiar with the spying principle - it's like a partial mocking of the testing object. The good article about it: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).

How it actually can be:

1. Your main class (let it be called "TestApp"):

```
public class TestApp {

    public void someRealMethod() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("A");
        items.add("B");
        items.add("C");
        items.add("D");
        items.add("E");

        items.forEach(lambdaForMocking());
        items.forEach(anotherLambdaForMocking());
    }

    Consumer<String> lambdaForMocking() {
        return item -> System.out.println(item);
    }

    Consumer<String> anotherLambdaForMocking() {
        return item -> {
            if ("C".equals(item)) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

2. Your test class:

```
public class TestAppTest {

    @Test
    public void lambdaMockingTest() {
        TestApp testApp = new TestApp();
        TestApp spy = Mockito.spy(testApp);

        Mockito.when(spy.lambdaForMocking()).thenReturn(item -> {});
        Mockito.when(spy.anotherLambdaForMocking()).thenReturn(item -> {});

        spy.someRealMethod();

        //Asserts...
    }
}
```

In "thenReturn" parts you can define any consumers that you want (I left them empty, for example).

Comment: Instead of returning Consumer make a function that conforms to consumer interface `void lambdaForMocking(String s)` and use it `items.forEach(this::lambdaForMocking);`.

Comment: @ImreL Ofc there are a lot of ways to make this code better. I just wanted to give to the OP the main idea of how to do what he needed.